# Combinatorics - Ordered Subgroup Formula Explained

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm reading through "Probability for the Enthusiastic Beginner" and there is a jump in explanation for subgroups that I don't understand.

**This is a quote from the book:**

*"If we denote by `N Pn` the number of ordered sets of n objects chosen from N objects (without repetition), then we can write our result as:"*

`N Pn = N(N − 1)(N − 2) · · · (N − (n − 1))`

Which I understand, it's basically another way to write N! but with the ending term: `(N − (n − 1))` but then...

*"If we multiply this by 1 in the form of (N − n)!/(N − n)!, we see that the number of ordered sets of n objects chosen from N objects can be written in the concise form,"*

```
N Pn = N! / ( N - n )! (ordered subgroups)
```

What?! Where did `(N − n)!/(N − n)!` come from and how does it explain the above formula? It makes no sense to me. I feel I need to understand this formula in order to proceed. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead:

$$\frac {N!}{(N-n)!}=\frac{N(N − 1) · · · 1}{(N-n)...1}$$

The numbers on the bottom line cancel out lots of right hand numbers on the top line.

What's left is

$$N(N-1)...(N-n+1)$$

Exactly what you want.

Comment: I see, because (N − n)! = (0)! = 1

Comment: No.  I've amended my answer to make the reason clearer.

Comment: and how is the new formula `N! / ( N - n )!` equivalent to the initial `N(N − 1)(N − 2) · · · (N − (n − 1))`?

Comment: Because you only multiplied the initial expression by 1.

Comment: but then it's dividing by `( N - n )!`. Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: Since the book proof is causing you a lot of difficulty consider the new way that I have explained it.